# How do wifi providers (like starbucks, at&t) determine if you have accepted terms or not?

Tags: http, redirect, server, wifi, router

When you connect to the wifi at a starbucks or to an at&t public wifi, you're presented with a website that makes you accept their terms and conditions before you can do anything else.

While you have not accepted these terms - regardless of what website you visit you will be redirected to the page that asks you to accept the terms.

How do the providers of the wifi know whether you have or have not accepted the terms?

How are they able to redirect your requests to their pages in the first place?

Comment: They might use something like http://dev.wifidog.org/

Answer (score 1):

They can redirect you anywhere as you're on their local network. They know if you accepted because of the [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of your device. Then they just check a table, which can be stored at their router, whether to redirect you or not.